# Подскажите как построить график

Tags: python-3.x

При фиксированном seed=42 поэкспериментируйте с параметрами алгоритма differential_evolution: strategy, popsize, mutation.

Постройте графики количества итераций (nit) оптимизации функции ackley от значения параметра.

```
def ackley(x):
    arg1 = -0.2 * np.sqrt(0.5 * (x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2))
    arg2 = 0.5 * (np.cos(2. * np.pi * x[0]) + np.cos(2. * np.pi * x[1]))`
    return -20. * np.exp(arg1) - np.exp(arg2) + 20. + np.e

bounds = [(-10, 10), (-10, 10)]

result = differential_evolution(ackley, bounds, seed=42, strategy='rand2bin', popsize=5, mutation=0.8)
result
```

Подскажите как построить график

Comment: взять лист бумаги, нарисовать оси координат, отметить имеющиеся точки, соединить их линией.

Comment: но меня больше интересует как это сделать в Python